# jOOQ - query builder with IN predicate

Tags: java, jooq

I am trying to build a query like this:

```
List<Integer> ids = ...

String query = DSL.select(TABLE.SOMETHING).from(TABLE).where(TABLE.ID.in(ids)).
getSQL();
```

But I am not able to get the generated query with the values, just the placeholders. 
I tried DSL.inline(ids) but it doesnt' work.

How can I do this?

I am using jOOQ 3.4.2.

Thanks for the help.

UPDATE:

Seems I can do this with:

```
    Configuration configuration = new DefaultConfiguration();
    configuration.set(SQLDialect.DERBY);
    Settings settings = new Settings()
    .withStatementType(StatementType.STATIC_STATEMENT);
    configuration.set(settings);
    DSLContext create = DSL.using(configuration);

    String query = create.select(TABLE.SOMETHING).from(TABLE).where(TABLE.ID.in(ids)).getSQL();
```

If someone can confirm that is th right way, thanks.

Comment: The solution with `STATIC_STATEMENT` is one valid option. I'll provide an answer with another one. You can answer your own stack overflow question, if you want...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot inline a list with jOOQ's [`DSL.inline()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#inline-T-) because if you could, the semantics of such a value would be that of a list/array literal in the database, not of a list of individual values.

#### Correct way to use `DSL.inline()`:

Here's one correct way to pass a list of inlined values to the [`Field.in(Field<?>...)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Field.html#in-org.jooq.Field...-):

```
List<Integer> ids = ...

String query = DSL.using(configuration) // Use a Configuration or at least a SQLDialect!
                  .select(TABLE.SOMETHING)
                  .from(TABLE)
                  .where(TABLE.ID.in(ids.stream().map(DSL::inline).collect(toList())))
                  .getSQL();
```

#### Inline all bind values on a per-`getSQL()` basis:

Use [`Query.getSQL(ParamType)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Query.html#getSQL-org.jooq.conf.ParamType-)

```
List<Integer> ids = ...

String query = DSL.using(configuration)
                  .select(TABLE.SOMETHING)
                  .from(TABLE)
                  .where(TABLE.ID.in(ids))
                  .getSQL(ParamType.INLINED);
```

#### Inline all bind values on a per-`Configuration` basis:

The solution you've mentioned in your question edit is valid as well, of course:

```
List<Integer> ids = ...
Configuration configuration = new DefaultConfiguration();
configuration.set(new Settings().withStatementType(StatementType.STATIC_STATEMENT));

String query = DSL.using(configuration)
                  .select(TABLE.SOMETHING)
                  .from(TABLE)
                  .where(TABLE.ID.in(ids))
                  .getSQL();
```